# add "please wait" javascript modal to aspx DetailView insert button

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Using insert functionality of an aspx DetailsView.  Would like to show a javascript modal popup window while the new record is processed and added to the database.  I can hook the button click in DetailsView_ItemCommand.  It's not working, so I started trying to figure out whats going on by simply displaying a javascript Alert() popup.  But can't get that to even work.  Here's the relevant DetailsView_ItemCommand:

```
    protected void DetailsViewInsertFPL_ItemCommand(object sender, DetailsViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Insert")
    {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "waitMessage", "alert('Please wait while your request is processed');", true);
        return;
    }
}
```

After the record is inserted, there is a redirect to another aspx page.

Can anyone steer me down the right path?  I'll be looking at some of the aspx page and DetailsView properties next to see if something there isn't set correct.

Comment: Place your `DetailView` into `asp:UpdatePanel` and add `asp:UpdateProgress`.

Comment: I'll give the asp:UpdatePanel and asp:UpdateProgress a go and see how that works.

Answer (score 0):

You cant just use

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "waitMessage", "alert('Please wait while your request is processed');", true);
```

then preceeded by a

```
response.redirect("toanotherpage.aspx");
```

ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript will render your script after all the elements in the page (right before the form's end tag) hence not executing it when you use response redirect on the same code block.

To achieve what you want you could do one of the following solutions,

1. Create a Javascript and place you the redirect or for this instance
   `window.location` there after the Alert message you want
2. Create a pop-up modal using other methods like bootstrap, on the modal declare a button with a code for response.redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Alex Kudryashev's suggestion to enclose the DetailView within an asp:UpdatePanel and use the asp:UpdateProgress to show the "please wait while your request is processed"  gave me the solution I needed in this case.

Infrequent user here, so not sure how to give the points to Alex as his suggestion was a comment rather than an answer.  Feel free to let me know how to handle the votes in that case.

Thanks!!!!   I've been banging my head against the wall for a couple of days to get this one working.